# Alternative to [CCNode convertToNodeSpace:] and [CCNode convertToWorldSpace:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a node which is scaled and moved every frame.

The node has a custom draw function, so that only the visible part of that node is drawn each frame.

To determine which part is visible, I need to call:

```
CGPoint start = [MyNode convertToNodeSpace:_adjustedStart];
CGPoint finish = [MyNode convertToNodeSpace:_adjustedFinish];
```

where:

```
_adjustedStart = CGPointZero;
_adjustedFinish = CGPointMake(_winSize.width, 0);
```

start.x and finish.x are used by my draw method, to determine the width to draw.

Prior to using these methods, I had 60fps, even though sometimes I would draw much more than necessary. After using these methods, I draw exactly the region necessary, but the framerate sometimes drops to 50 (for an instant), making the graphics choppy.

How can I perform the same calculation as convertToNodeSpace / convertToWorldSpace but faster?

Comment: did you test fps on a device? in release build? did you analyze performance with instruments or A/B testing to ensure the problem is with this particular code?

Comment: I did test fps on a device, and did analyse using instruments. This is the only code that has changed. Instead of setting start and finish to a calculation (position + win size.width *range), I use the above. The problem is, that is not a steady 50fps. Most of the time it is 60, and drop to 50fps for an instant every couple of seconds.

Comment: and you run the converttoNodeSpace every couple of seconds? I wouldn't think so. I find it more likely that the app was on the brink of dropping below 60 fps and now for the first time you're seeing the effect of say, creating a dozen or more sprites in a single frame. You might want to have a closer look where that occassional drop is coming from, ie focus on the code that runs in sync with the fps drops, like anything scheduled to run every couple seconds. Also just to avoid the possibility: reboot your device, and be sure not to use a jailbroken one.

Comment: Nothing is scheduled to run every couple of seconds. The same code, runs every frame. I think dropping from 60 - 50 fps is pretty substantial. Do you know how to figure out what code is causing a momentary FPS drop ? Also, I create at most 2 sprites every frame.

Comment: enable the debug stats and check how many draw calls you create. Shouldn't be more than 20-50. Above 30 I would look into optimizing draw calls with batch nodes first and foremost. CPU usage is rarely a problem in iOS games. Unless it's being thrashed with frequent alloc/dealloc cycles or resource loading. Ie if your sprites created require them to first load their image then that's a likely problem. One that's easily solved with texture atlases.

Comment: I have 2 draw calls every frame. Sometimes 3.